# 3D Grid for boxes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, grids

How to create 3d Grid for this boxes behind the black rectangle? I am using Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

I tried create isometric grid for it, but it didn't fit.

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  What have you tried? What has failed? What problem are you having?

Comment: Hi. Your question is a bit unclear to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please don't remove valuable parts of the question.

Answer (score 4):

It's a series of simple shapes..

- 2 rectangles, rotated 45°
- Draw straight vertical and horizontal path
- Select everything and align on vertical center and horizontal center
- Hit the `Divide` button on the Pathfinder Panel
- Delete unwanted pieces, color other pieces
- Copy and position duplicates of this
- Delete individual sections as desired.

[image]

This can easily be made into a pattern fill as well... but expanding the pattern to remove sections is a process in itself.

[image]

---

The shapes in the example aren't perfect squares. They are more of a diamond. But this method works for just about anything...

[image]

You can even create the image at the 45° angles, taking advantage of constraining and smart guides. Then merely "squish" the result to get the same perspective...

[image]

Comment: I love seeing things like this :D

Comment: I think OP's problem is that the projection isn't perfect isometric - 120 degrees between axes.  But I don't think it based on the 45 degree rotation you've created either - the angles are slightly off.

Comment: @pbasdf My goal is **not** to provide a "here's a complete step-by-step guide to your *exact* issue" Few actually *learn* anything that way. I provide methodology which can *easily* be translated to any specific project. While you are correct, it's not a perfect 45° angle. It's a bit more of a short diamond. However, this methodology is exactly the same for the [non-square shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hey7j.png).

Comment: In fact, you can do the above at 45° then simply ["squish" the final result vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhbTC.png) to get the same angles.

Comment: @Scott Thanks - I appreciate the time you put into your answers and I learn a lot from them.  Your comment, and the attached image - has helped me to see how to apply your method more generally.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The image is put together of skewed rectangles, but there's no need to calculate anything.

I zoomed your image to so big size that I could draw accurately a couple of lines over it. The black line is the longer side of the yellow skewed rectangle and the red line is the vertical side. Hold shift when you draw it to make it exactly vertical.

[image]

Duplicate the lines. Move the pieces to their places and join them (=Ctrl+J) to get a closed
skewed rectangle.

[image]

To make the placements exactly you must have smart guides and snap to points ON. No other snaps!

Learn the common "Drag a corner with the direct selection tool" -trick for exact placements:

Select a piece. Drag its end node with the direct selection tool. The dragged node snaps. The normal selection tool turns temporarily to the direct selection tool if you hold Ctrl.

After joining the pieces remove the stroke and pick the yellow fill color.

Make with Object > Transform > Reflect a flipped copy and color it to orange.

[image]

Make copies and tile manually the wanted pattern. Looks simple, but the layering order is important and corners must snap against each other.

Here's a few parts placed:

[image]

I made a group (=selected) where the orange half is on the top. It's easier to place 2 items together. Ungroup later and delete the extra pieces at the edges.

It's important to use carefully the "select and drag one node with the direct selection tool" -trick to get the parts placed exactly.

You get a new copy of a piece by selecting it, copying  to the clipboard (Ctrl+C) and pasting (Ctrl+V). The pasted copy is automatically on the top, so you can build the pattern without a need to bring anything to front nor to send anything to back.

If you make a layering order error you can move parts up and down in the Layers panel.

BTW. Illustrators 3D ExtrudeBevel can be used to pull crossing lines to walls:

[image]

The lines are grouped before applying the effect. That makes the effect understand some walls are in front of the others. You do not get it right if you only select all lines and apply 3D> Extrude&Bevel

The lines are rotated 45 degrees to make the settings of the view angles simpler in the effect dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

See the top most orange bar going from upper left to lower right? What you'll do is draw only the part of the panel from the left up to where it meets the yellow bar. You'll see that that shape is used repeatedly over the drawing. (In other words, don't draw the entire length of the bar. Don't do overlapping of objects.)

Now look at the same orange bar, but the far right side. That's a different shape. Draw and duplicate the shape.

Duplicate the first object and butt them together and add the other end piece.

Group everything. Duplicate and space apart.

Group everything. Duplicate it and color it yellow.

Flip it right to left to form the yellow bars going in the other direction. Adjust to fit.